# Upload/Downloading files to Google Drive in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, google-drive-api

I am able to sign into Google using the [web authentication sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122/sourcecode?fileId=52289&pathId=1917124598). Here's the code:

```
    private async void Launch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {    
        if(GoogleClientID.Text == "") 
        { 
            rootPage.NotifyUser("Please enter an Client ID.", NotifyType.StatusMessage); 
        } 
        else if(GoogleCallbackUrl.Text == "") 
        { 
            rootPage.NotifyUser("Please enter an Callback URL.", NotifyType.StatusMessage); 
        } 

        try 
        { 
            String GoogleURL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(GoogleClientID.Text) + "&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(GoogleCallbackUrl.Text) + "&response_type=code&scope=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("http://picasaweb.google.com/data"); 

            System.Uri StartUri = new Uri(GoogleURL); 
            // When using the desktop flow, the success code is displayed in the html title of this end uri 
            System.Uri EndUri = new Uri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?"); 

            DebugPrint("Navigating to: " + GoogleURL); 

            WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync( 
                                                    WebAuthenticationOptions.UseTitle, 
                                                    StartUri, 
                                                    EndUri); 
            if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success) 
            { 
                OutputToken(WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.ToString()); 
            } 
            else if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp) 
            { 
                OutputToken("HTTP Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : " + WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseErrorDetail.ToString()); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                OutputToken("Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : " + WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus.ToString()); 
            } 
        } 
        catch (Exception Error) 
        { 
            // 
            // Bad Parameter, SSL/TLS Errors and Network Unavailable errors are to be handled here. 
            // 
            DebugPrint(Error.ToString()); 
        } 
}
```

After the app authenticates, I'm not sure how to go about using file operations. Their is a .Net library that Google has made available but it doesn't seem to work for Windows store apps.

Here is the doc upload files over http:

Google Drive api: https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads

I tried using the [HttpClient sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HttpClient-sample-55700664) but wasn't sure how to use the authentication token that I got from the authentication sample.

Comment: There is no reason the SDK you linked to cannot be used for Windows Store applications.

Comment: The SDK I linked to? If you're talking about the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads), then yes, I can use it, I'm just not sure how.

Comment: Start by implementing it on a desktop application.  If one looks hard enough there is even a unofficial Windows Phone application with source.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'd be best served using the [BackgroundUploader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounduploader.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) class in WinRT, and then putting your auth token into the Authorization header using the [SetRequestHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounduploader.setrequestheader.aspx) method. The `BackgroundUploader` should handle the parts of your file (based on the Google Drive documentation and the MSDN docs) so with the headers and method below, I think that's all you need.

```
POST /upload/drive/v2/files?uploadType=media HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: {number_of_bytes_in_JPEG_file}
Authorization: {your_auth_token}

{JPEG data}
```

For smaller file types, you should be able to do something similar with `System.Net.HttpClient` - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679214/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-header-for-an-httpclient-request) is a post about setting headers on that type.