# If Modified Since HttpWebRequest windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have to download a file from an http server only if the date is changed

if i insert in a request

```
request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp("http://myserver.....");
request.Headers["If-Modified-Since"] = previousValue;
```

receive errors

in a Windows phone 8 it is possible?

Thank you

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: check out the answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976587/set-or-read-date-in-http-header-windows-phone-8