# parsing from website which return 403 forbidden

Tags: c#, parsing, xaml, windows-8, store

Actually, I'm programming a windows store application, I try to parse a website, but the response return that it has an error in the request is not required.
I have a snapshot that maybe help us to find a solution
this code worked with all website I tried, but there is not working.

I use this sourcecode :

```
private async void parsingActualites()
    {
        HttpClient http = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        HttpClientHandler newClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        ***var reponse = await http.GetByteArrayAsync("http://.........../");***
        str3 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(reponse, 0, reponse.Length - 1);
        var strdecodet = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(str3);
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document2 = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        document2.LoadHtml(str3);
```

the error that showed to me is :

> Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).

Res

this is a picture to describe more the error please can you help me  :)

Comment: Can you browse to the url with to access?

Comment: yes i can , it is working 100%

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There could be several reasons for what you are experiencing. For example - the site may require authentication which your program does not perform but you did manually while browsing. Or the website is expecting headers which your program does not provide.

The right way to solve this issue is to understand what the browser does and you don't. Download [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/), run it and then browse to the url. Fiddler will display the actual requests made by your browser. Here's an example - [image: Fiddler example].

As you can see, the browser sends several more headers you should do the same (actually you should find the minimal set that works). To add headers - take a look at http://massivescale.com/pages/custom-headers-with-httpclient/ or [How do you set the Content-Type header for an HttpClient request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679214/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-header-for-an-httpclient-request)

Comment: the same problem , using user-agent is not a solution ! the same message 403 forbidden

Comment: @MedMans - 1. Did you add all the headers that the browser sends? 2. Does the site require authentication? 3. Could you post a screenshot of fiddler when you browse the site (you can censor everything but the headers) and your code?

Comment: i verified my code , the problem is solved now , i just changed the put method to get method , thank u very much ! (y)

Answer (score 14):

There are some web servers which expect to receive a `User-Agent` header in the request (and they return 403 if they don't see one). You can add a `User-Agent` header for example as follows:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,"http://example.com");
// Add our custom headers
requestMessage.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "User-Agent-Here");
HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);
```

Comment: I had the same problem with some web sites and this worked for me. In fact, performing a GET request on any Stackoverflow page would return StatusCode 403. After setting any User Agent in the headers it returns StatusCode 200 OK. Thank you.