# How to pass content-type in http client using C#?

Tags: dotnet-httpclient

How to pass below content-type in http client using C# ?

```
multipart/alternative;  
boundary=56CC414C-FDE6-48DB-846C-6A1CEBCD7805;  
type=\"text/plain\"
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679214/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-header-for-an-httpclient-request

Comment: I want to above line in Content-Type header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work,

```
var multipartContent = new MultipartContent("alternative","56CC414C-FDE6-48DB-846C-6A1CEBCD7805");
multipartContent.Add(new StringContent("Here is some content"));

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.PostAsync("http://example.org/",multipartContent);
```