# Content-Type httpClient to get response using c#

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I need to get response from url using the following headers:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-apiKey", App.API_Key);
string responseAsString = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://......./");
```

it stop running at this line without any value for responseAsString:

```
 httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679214/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-header-for-an-httpclient-request

Comment: Any errors? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: `Content-Type` is a response, not a request header. If you check the response status of your call I suspect you received a `400` error. Use the `Accept` header to specify the format you want

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I suggest you to read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) or [this](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046)

Comment: @RockThunder no errors

Comment: @tanaydin not effective in this case

Comment: @HamletHakobyan `GetStringAsync` is a `GET` request. `GET` requests have no body, hence no `Content-Type` is allowed

Comment: @ahmad what is the HTTP response status code? Use `SendAsync` to get the actual response object or use Fiddler to check what the server actually returns.

Comment: here is the problem 
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, "Content-Type is a response, not a request header." this is from your comment.