# Post JSON with multiply lines in C#?

Tags: c#, json, post, httpwebrequest

Im in trouble, how i can write post data like this(code below) with **Content-Type: application/json** in C#?

```
{
  "snippet": {
    "data": "t1",
    "data2": "t2",
    "data3": "t3",
    "data4": "t4"
  },
  "data": {
    "st": "bxx"
  }
}
```

Damn guys, i can't undestand how i can use JSON Serialization with my code:( Help pls little girl:D Im a newbuy. Put please {
 "snippet": {
  "data": "t1",
  "data2": "t2",
  "data3": "t3",
  "data4": "t4"
 },
 "data": {
  "st": "bxx"
 }
}

with JSON Serialization in my code:

var resultHttpPost = ZK.HttpPost("https://urlcom", "here is need be code with json", "application/json", "", "iso-8859-1", ZK.InterfacesLibrary.Z.Http.ResponceType.HeaderAndBody);

I just can't understand how i merge it and put right escapes in json code:(

`{
  "snippet\": {
    "data\": "t1",
    "data2\": "t2",
    "data3\": "t3",
    "data4\": "t4"
  },
  "data\": {
    "st\": "bxx"
  }
}`
Doesnt worked:(

Comment: Q: How can I post (JSON) data?  A: You can google "C# JSON", and find links like this: [JSON Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Q: How can I post multi-line JSON data?  A: The format is irrelevant.  As far as the HTTP message - it doesn't matter if it's one line, or multiple lines,.

Comment: lots or working example can be located here.. good luck [C# Working Examples JSON](http://www.google.com)

Comment: I was googling it, its doesnt heping me.. In example what link you give me there is json in one line({“age”:42,”name”:”John”}) but i have multiply lines. I need make post request with separated by newline

Comment: Why do you think you need to make the request separated by newline?  It is usually just printed that way for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You've really got three separate questions here:

Q1) How can I post (JSON) data?

A: You can google "C# JSON", and find links like this: [JSON Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Q2) How can I post multi-line JSON data?

A: The format is irrelevant. As far as the HTTP message - it doesn't matter if it's one line, or multiple lines.  "Formatting" is a presentation issue - JSON parsers will read exactly the same message with or without formatting.

If you *want* to present in a "fomatted" form, then:

a) you must *not* send as "Content-Type: application/json".  You should use "text/plain" or "html/text" instead

... and ...

b) you should use the HTML [`<pre>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) tag to preserve formatting.

Q3) How do I set "Content-Type"?

That depends entirely on what library you're using to create and send your HTTP data.

Here is one possibility:

[How do you set the Content-Type header for an HttpClient request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679214/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-header-for-an-httpclient-request)

```
HttpClient c = new HttpClient();
c.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://example.com/");
c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
...
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON should be in single quotes and you will need "+" operator for concatenation. 
Your JSON should look like this.

```
"{"+
  "'snippet': {"+
    "'data': 't1',"+
    "'data2': 't2',"+
    "'data3': 't3',"+
    "'data4': 't4'"+
  "},"+
  "'data': {"+
    "'st': bxx'"+
  "}"+
"}";
```