# Can't set Content-Type header

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, httpclient, flurl

I'm having trouble setting the Content-Type on HttpClient.
I followed along this question: [How do you set the Content-Type header for an HttpClient request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679214/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-header-for-an-httpclient-request)
But still no luck.

```
String rcString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new RoadsmartChecks() { userguid = user_guid, coords = coordinates, radius = (radius * 100) + "" }, ROADSMART_JSON_FORMAT, JSONNET_SETTINGS);
HttpClient c = new HttpClient();
c.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);
c.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json"); //Keeps returning false
c.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization", hash_aes);
c.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Roadsmart-app", Constant.APP_ID);
c.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Roadsmart-user", user_guid);
c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, BASE_URL + URL_CHECKS + "/fetch");
req.Content = new StringContent(rcString);
await c.SendAsync(req).ContinueWith(respTask =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Response: {0}", respTask.Result);
});
```

[image: Debugger]
I also tried by using the Flurl library, but it crashes when trying to add the 'Content-Type'.

```
misused header name content-type
```

So how can I force it so it really adds it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you should try this

```
req.Content = new StringContent(rcString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

checkout this links :

[How do you set the Content-Type header for an HttpClient request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679214/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-header-for-an-httpclient-request)

### Edit

Remove this line `c.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");` and check

Comment: Now, the header is being set which is one thing. 
But I'm getting a 403. In Postman however the request returns json.

Comment: @TimRijckaert it means it is not able to accept json result.

Comment: Hmm, Yeah I see the problem now. One of my headers has "\"value"\". So I need to unescape the string.

Answer (score 3):

***UPDATE: See [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46920875/62600) for non-default content types***

With Flurl you shouldn't need to set Content-Type to application/json for methods like `PostJsonAsync`. This is the default content type in this case and it will get set for you.

Comment: Well it seemed a parameter of my was wrongly converted so I'll give Flurl another try as it simplifed the code much. Thanks

Comment: Until you encounter an api that actually requires you to set a Content-Type header on the POST request :-/

Comment: @qes are you saying you're posting JSON formatted data and yet the API requires you set a Content-Type _other_ than application/json?

Comment: @ToddMenier It's a soap xml api for flight data and I have to set it to text/xml while post'ing the xml request body or else the api returns a 415. I may have missed it, but I wasn't able to figure out how to get Flurl to do that. Ajay's solution above using HttpClient works for me, though.

Comment: @qes did you try `.WithHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml")` in the flurl call?

Comment: @ToddMenier Yes, it results in an invalid operation exception: Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects. It comes from System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.Add(...)

Answer (score 2):

The latest and greatest answer to this with Flurl is to [upgrade](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl.Http/). 2.0 introduces several enhancements in the headers dept:

1. They're no longer validated. Flurl now uses `TryAddWithoutValidation` under the hood, so you'll never get the "misused header name" error with the `WithHeader(s)` methods. (I always found that validation behavior to be a bit overprotective.)
2. In a fluent call they're set at the individual request level rather than the `FlurlClient` level, so you won't run into [concurrency issues](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/157) when reusing the client.
3. Since hyphens are common in header names but not allowed in C# identifiers, there's a [new convention](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/44) where underscores are converted to hyphens so you don't have to give up object notation when specifying multiple:

   ```
   url.WithHeaders(new { Content_Type = "foo", ... }
   ```