# Specifying content language for JSON request with Flurl?

Tags: c#, header, http-headers, flurl

## Issue

I would like to `POST` a `JSON` request using Flurl with the content header `Content-Language` specified. I already managed to set the content type (`Content-Type`) without any issues:

```
string response = await "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/".AppendPathSegment("posts")
            .WithHeaders(new { Content_Type = "application/json; charset=UTF-8" })
            .PostJsonAsync(new { title = "bar", body = "foo", userId = 1 }).ReceiveString();

Console.WriteLine(response);
```

correctly returning:

```
{
  "title": "bar",
  "body": "foo",
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 102
}
```

However, trying to specify `Content-Language` in addition:

```
string response = await "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/".AppendPathSegment("posts")
            .WithHeaders(new { Content_Type = "application/json; charset=UTF-8", Content_Language = "en-US" })
            .PostJsonAsync(new { title = "bar", body = "foo", userId = 1 }).ReceiveString();

Console.WriteLine(response);
```

breaks the code giving the error

> Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.

I understand that content headers should be set on the content and not the request, however, after reading this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46369967/7061914) (and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46920875/7061914)) it seemed like there's no need to distinct request and content levels anymore with Flurl 2.0+.

### Side note

The used API is a mock. I'm aware that using `PostJsonAsync` automatically sets the `Content-Type` header, however, for my use case, it will be set to `application/vnd.api+json` and therefore, needs to be specified explicitly.

## Question

**What am I doing wrong? Is there anything I do not understand about content headers?

What makes `Content-Language` any different from `Content-Type` when adding it to a request?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone stumbling across the same issue: it's a bug. I filed an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/405) and the maintainer approved it, saying it'll be fixed on the next release (supposedly [Flurl.Http 2.4.1](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/milestone/29)).
In addition to `Content-Language`, the headers `Allow` and `Content-Encoding` are also missing and will throw the same error as described in the issue.