# How to set character set of URL which is called from GetMethod in Java?

Tags: java, servlets, encoding, getmethod

I am trying to call url from java servlet with GetMethod:

```
HttpMethod method = new GetMethod(url);
method.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=" + "UTF-8");
```

Error message:

```
Invalid uri 'https://test.com/test?partner_deal=deal&username=Arto.Kank¿¿¿¿': Invalid query
```

It seems that problem is with encoding, because username should be Arto.Kankää
How to fix it?

Comment: URLs don't have charsets, they have a defined encoding. It is the *content* of the URL that has a charset. You need to encode your URL correctly.

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679214/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-header-for-an-httpclient-request)

Comment: `URLEncoder.encode("Arto.Kankää")` could help?