# MSDN example on async/await - can't I reach the break point after the await call?

Tags: c#, async-await

In trying MSDN's example on async/await, why I can't reach a break point after the await operator ?

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AccessTheWebAsync();
}

private async Task<int> AccessTheWebAsync()
{ 
    // You need to add a reference to System.Net.Http to declare client.
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    // GetStringAsync returns a Task<string>. That means that when you await the
    // task you'll get a string (urlContents).
    Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");

    // You can do work here that doesn't rely on the string from GetStringAsync.
    /*** not relevant here ***/
    //DoIndependentWork();

    // The await operator suspends AccessTheWebAsync.
    //  - AccessTheWebAsync can't continue until getStringTask is complete.
    //  - Meanwhile, control returns to the caller of AccessTheWebAsync.
    //  - Control resumes here when getStringTask is complete. 
    //  - The await operator then retrieves the string result from getStringTask.
    string urlContents = await getStringTask;

    // The return statement specifies an integer result.
    // Any methods that are awaiting AccessTheWebAsync retrieve the length value.
    return urlContents.Length;
}
```

My understanding is that the await is a construct that abstracts the asynchronous flow from the developer - leaving him/her as if working synchronously. In other words, in the code above, I do not care about how and when the `getStringTask` finishes, I care only about it finishing and using its results. I would expect then to be able to reach the break point after the await call at sometime.

[image]

Comment: Because there wasn't any response from the server yet? `await` means execution will continue after the awaited task finishes, either on the original thread (on Windows Forms) or another thread (eg in ASP.NET)

Comment: It looks quite far-fetched that such a simple http get could take more than 1 or 2 seconds, whereas I do run hundreds of http get requests for other urls (using `.Result`) within 1 or 2 seconds. I posted this question as a follow up to someone asking me if there is any reason I use `.Result` instead of `async/await`. Well, this is the reason. I have working stuff with `.Result`, and when I *move* them to `async/await`, it's as if they no longer do. In any case, leaving only the break point after the await call, will never put me there - since the console app ends/exits.

Comment: To prove my point, replacing `string urlContents = await getStringTask` with `var urlContents = getStringTask.Result;` will lend me at the break point I want, at `Console.WriteLine(urlContents.Length)` after approximately 2 seconds.

Comment: Whoever asked about `.Result` was correct. There is no magic or bug with `await` and the two snippets do something completely different. The first one executes asynchronously. The second one doesn't. If you suspect something went wrong with `await` put a try/catch around it to catch possible exceptions, check your code, pause and open the Parallel Stacks debug window to see what's going on. Don't assume that a foundational feature used in thousands of projects is broken

Comment: PS. just noticed that you call your asynchronous method from a console window *without* awaiting for the results. Thus your process terminates before your task has a chance to finish - it probably doesn't even have a chance to send the request. Either block in your `Main` until the async method returns, or store its result to a Task variable and call `.Result` on it

Comment: I never suggested something is broken, do not make assumptions on what others may have assumed :-). It makes no sense to assume it is broken, for the very same reason you advocate. I am taking a look at your responses and will update after I reached new conclusions.

Comment: On your last comment: in other words, using `Result` when you want to access the result is not a bad practice - you need the task terminated in any case. The bad practice is to chain asynchronous calls relying on `Result` as input. Because this will defeat the async capability / will make everything sync. Is this correct ?

Comment: No, you misunderstood. It *is* a bad practice because it causes blocking. The problem in your code was that you fired off an asynchronous method but didn't wait for it to finish before exiting the process. In a WPF, WinForms or ASP.NET application you wouldn't need to use `.Result` at all because the process doesn't terminate when an event handler finishes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You call your asynchronous method from a Console application's Main method without waiting for the async method to finish. As a result, your process terminates before your task has a chance to complete.

Since you can't convert a Console application's Main to an asynchronous (`async Task`) method, you'll have to block on the asynchronous method, by calling `Wait` or `.Result`:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    AccessTheWebAsync().Wait();
}
```

or

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{ 
    var webTask=AccessTheWebAsync();
    //... do other work until the resuls is actually needed
    var pageSize=webTask.Result;
    //... now use the returned page size
}
```

Comment: In other words, using Result when you want to access the final result is not a bad practice - you need the task terminated in any case. The bad practice is to chain asynchronous calls relying on Result as input. Because this will defeat the async capability / will make everything sync. Is this correct ?

Comment: No, using .Result *is* a very bad practice. In this case it's necessary because you don't have any way other than `.Result` or `.Wait()` to wait for your asynchronous method to finish, before your `Main()` does.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses, Panagiotis.