# Does async bring any benefit in this example?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to learn the `async` and `await` mechanisms in C#.

The [simplest example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) is clear to me.

The line

```
Task<string> getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
```

triggers an asynchronous web call. The control returns to `AccessTheWebAsync()`. It is free to perform `DoIndependentWork()`. After doing this it waits for the completion of the task `getStringTask` and when this result is available the function executes the next line 
`return urlContents.Length;` 
So, as far as I understand the purpose of the `async` call is to let the caller execute other operations when the operation tagged with `async` is in progress.

However, I'm bit confused with the [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh300224(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1), in this function.

```
    private async Task<byte[]> GetURLContentsAsync(string url)
    {
        // The downloaded resource ends up in the variable named content. 
        var content = new MemoryStream();

        // Initialize an HttpWebRequest for the current URL. 
        var webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        // Send the request to the Internet resource and wait for 
        // the response.                 
        using (WebResponse response = await webReq.GetResponseAsync())

        // The previous statement abbreviates the following two statements. 

        //Task<WebResponse> responseTask = webReq.GetResponseAsync(); 
        //using (WebResponse response = await responseTask)
        {
            // Get the data stream that is associated with the specified url. 
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                // Read the bytes in responseStream and copy them to content. 
                await responseStream.CopyToAsync(content);

                // The previous statement abbreviates the following two statements. 

                // CopyToAsync returns a Task, not a Task<T>. 
                //Task copyTask = responseStream.CopyToAsync(content); 

                // When copyTask is completed, content contains a copy of 
                // responseStream. 
                //await copyTask;
            }
        }
        // Return the result as a byte array. 
        return content.ToArray();
    }
```

Inside the method `GetURLContentsAsync()`, there are two async invocations. However, the API waits with an `await` call on both. The caller is not doing anything **between** the trigger of the `async` operation and the receipt of the data. So, as far as I understand, the `async/await` mechanism brings no benefit here. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Why don't you post the code the actual question is about?

Comment: It will **not** block the UI thread. Huge benefit, isn't it?

Comment: Apparently not directly related, but I had [problems in understanding the examples as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35575734/1219280).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code doesn't need to explicitly be doing anything between `await`'d async calls to gain benefit. It means that the thread isn't sitting waiting for each call to complete, it is available to do other work.

If this is a web application it can result in more requests being processed. If it is a Windows application it means the UI thread isn't blocked and the user has a better experience.

Comment: _"the user has a better experience"_ especially when the request might take long or time out (which can always happen due to networking)

Comment: "It means that the thread isn't sitting waiting for each call to complete, it is available to do other work" => But only if I utilize it do something as in the first example, right? In the UI thread example this is benefited because the WPF or whatever framework has other code to execute while my function is suspended on await, right?

Comment: If the UI thread isn't blocked the user can resize, move etc and it can be redrawn immediately as the ui thread is free.

Comment: OK, this means there is some other code (UI, which I can't see) that is being executed in the context of the current thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> However, the API waits with an await call on both.

You will have to await for the both because your method code should get executed sequentially, if you don't await the first call, your next lines of code will also get executed which is something you might not expect or need to happen.

The following two reasons that come in my mind for awaiting both methods are:

- it is possible that your first async method result is used as
  parameter in your second async method call
- it is also possible that we decide on the result of first async
  method call that the second async method to be called or not

So if that's the case then it is quite clear why you would not need to add `await` to every async method call inside your `async` method.

### EDIT:

From the example which you are pointing to clearly you can see that the output of first async method is being used in the second async method call here:

```
using (WebResponse response = await webReq.GetResponseAsync())

            // The previous statement abbreviates the following two statements. 

            //using (WebResponse response = await responseTask)
            {
                // Get the data stream that is associated with the specified url. 
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    // Read the bytes in responseStream and copy them to content. 
                    await responseStream.CopyToAsync(content);

                    // The previous statement abbreviates the following two statements. 

                    // CopyToAsync returns a Task, not a Task<T>. 
                    //Task copyTask = responseStream.CopyToAsync(content); 

                    // When copyTask is completed, content contains a copy of 
                    // responseStream. 
                    //await copyTask;
                }
            }
```

Comment: I understand why there are await on both APIs. But my understanding is that this means there is really no benefit with the await in this example. This is one of the first examples in MSDN and I found it bit strange that they write a piece of code which doesn't clearly illustrate the benefit of a new feature and I was wondering if I understood something wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

GetResponseAsync returns when the web server starts its response (by sending the headers), while CopyToAsync returns once all the data has been sent from the server and copied to the other stream.

If you add code to record how much time elapses between the start of the asynchronous call and the return to your function, you'll see that both methods take some time to complete (on a large file, at least.)

```
private static async Task<byte[]> GetURLContentsAsync(string url) {
    var content = new MemoryStream();

    var webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    DateTime responseStart = DateTime.Now;
    using (WebResponse response = await webReq.GetResponseAsync()) {
        Console.WriteLine($"GetResponseAsync time: {(DateTime.Now - responseStart).TotalSeconds}");

        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
            DateTime copyStart = DateTime.Now;
            await responseStream.CopyToAsync(content);
            Console.WriteLine($"CopyToAsync time: {(DateTime.Now - copyStart).TotalSeconds}");
        }
    }

    return content.ToArray();
}
```

For a ~40 MB file on a fast server, the first await is quick while the second await takes longer.

```
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/thunderbird/releases/52.2.1/win32/en-US/Thunderbird%20Setup%2052.2.1.exe
GetResponseAsync time: 0.3422409
CopyToAsync time: 5.3175731
```

But for a server that takes a while to respond, the first await can take a while too.

```
http://www.fakeresponse.com/api/?sleep=3
GetResponseAsync time: 3.3125195
CopyToAsync time: 0
```