# How to post form-data IFormFile with HttpClient?

Tags: c#, http, post, asp.net-core, multipartform-data

I have backend endpoint `Task<ActionResult> Post(IFormFile csvFile)` and I need to call this endpoint from HttpClient. Currently I am getting `Unsupported media type error`.
Here is my code:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine("IntegrationTests", "file.csv");
var gg = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
var byteArrayContent = new ByteArrayContent(gg);
var postResponse = await _client.PostAsync("offers", new MultipartFormDataContent
{
    {byteArrayContent }
});
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40680451/9363973) solution from another StackOverflow question

Comment: Thanks but it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to specify parameter name in `MultipartFormDataContent` collection matching action parameter name (`csvFile`) and a random file name

```
var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
multipartContent.Add(byteArrayContent, "csvFile", "filename");
var postResponse = await _client.PostAsync("offers", multipartContent);
```

or equivalent

```
var postResponse = await _client.PostAsync("offers", new MultipartFormDataContent {
    { byteArrayContent, "csvFile", "filename" }
});
```

Comment: Thanks I was missing this headers:
content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
            {
                Name = "csvFile",
                FileName = fileName
            };
            content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
            content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryMRxYYlVt8KWT8TU3");

Comment: What if my type is not the `IFormFile`, but the `List<IFormFile>`? Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Use this snippet:

```
const string url = "https://localhost:5001/api/Upload";
const string filePath = @"C:\Path\To\File.png";

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var form = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        using (var fs = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            using (var streamContent = new StreamContent(fs))
            {
                using (var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(await streamContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()))
                {
                    fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");

                    // "file" parameter name should be the same as the server side input parameter name
                    form.Add(fileContent, "file", Path.GetFileName(filePath));
                    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, form);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was missing `MediaTypeHeaderValue` on `fileContent.Headers.ContentType` and `fileContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");` save my life

Comment: 3/5 of your using statements could be simplified to one line `var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(filePath));`

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me as a generic

```
public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormDataAsync<T>(this HttpClient httpClient, string url, string token, T data)
    {
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        foreach (var prop in data.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var value = prop.GetValue(data);
            if (value is FormFile)
            {
                var file = value as FormFile;
                content.Add(new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream()), prop.Name, file.FileName);
                content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data") { Name = prop.Name, FileName = file.FileName };
            }
            else
            {
                content.Add(new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value)), prop.Name);
            }
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        return httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
    }
```

Comment: Can u write example of api controller ?any custom model required for file with json data

Answer (score 4):

Solved by using this code:

```
        const string fileName = "csvFile.csv";
        var filePath = Path.Combine("IntegrationTests", fileName);
        var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        var content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(bytes));
        form.Add(content, "csvFile");
        content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
        {
            Name = "csvFile",
            FileName = fileName
        };
        content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
        content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryMRxYYlVt8KWT8TU3");
        form.Add(content);

        //Act
        var postResponse = await _sellerClient.PostAsync("items/upload", form);
```

Comment: What is the boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryMRxYYlVt8KWT8TU3 ??

Answer (score 3):

Please see the following working code with .NET 5.0 Environment.

You send the file as a byte[] and receive it as a IFormFile in the API.

```
//api controller receiver

[HttpPost("SendBackupFiles")]
public IActionResult SendBackupFiles(IFormFile file)
{
    var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

    using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath)) 
        file.CopyToAsync(stream);
}



//client code sender example, not optimized lol.

const string filePath = @"C:\temp\hallo.csv";

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
               
    byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

    ByteArrayContent byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileData);

    byteContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");
    
    form.Add(byteContent, "file", Path.GetFileName(filePath));

    var result = httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:5070/..yourControllerName.../SendBackupFiles", form).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult().Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

Comment: This worked out well helping me. What you do here is to wrap IFormFile'ize the byte array. That corresponds to the question asked (i.e. how to adapt sender to the recipient. However, I'm curious, what if we for some reason can't, don't want to or simply won't adapt the sender? It's hardly sufficient to change the type in the controller to `byte[]` instead of `IFormFile`, is it? What would you recommend in such case?

Answer (score 2):

Post the attachment as an **MultipartFormDataContent**

```
var type = typeof(Startup);
            var stream = type.Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(type, "Resources.New.docx");
        var fileContent = new StreamContent(stream);
var data = new MultipartFormDataContent
            {
                { fileContent, "file", "New.docx" }
            };

        var response = await _client.PostAsync("upload", multipartContent);
```

Source: https://medium.com/@woeterman_94/c-webapi-upload-files-to-a-controller-e5ccf288b0ca