# Posting a File to a Controller - IFormFiles are always empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to make a POST request that sends files to a controller method with the following definition

```
public async Task<ActionResult> PostUploadFilesAsync([BindRequired, FromForm] IEnumerable<IFormFile> files)
```

But 'files' is always empty when it receives the request.

I've tried a few different ways of posting it, and this is my current attempt at building up the request. The files I'm sending have been uploaded to my own controller and seem fine at that point.

```
  var client = new HttpClient();
  var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  await Request.Form.Files[0].CopyToAsync(ms);
  content.Add(new StreamContent(ms));
  var address = <the-address>;
  var result = client.PostAsync(address, content);
```

I can't figure out why the files are not being received. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55458895/9695286 this answer may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two issues with the code you've posted:

1. When calling `Add` on the `MultipartFormDataContent` instance, you need to specify both a *name* and a *filename*. The *name* parameter must match the parameter being used in `PostUploadFilesAsync`:

   ```
   content.Add(new StreamContent(ms), "files", "file1");
   ```

   You can do this multiple times, to add multiple files. For example:

   ```
   content.Add(new StreamContent(ms1), "files", "file1");
   content.Add(new StreamContent(ms2), "files", "file2");
   ```
2. After you copy the contents of `Request.Form.Files[0]` into the `MemoryStream`, `ms`, you must also reset the position of the stream. Otherwise, the content sent to the server will be empty, as it will begin from the current position of the stream, which is at the end. Here's an example of resetting the position before adding the content:

   ```
   ms.Position = 0;
   content.Add(new StreamContent(ms));
   ```

Comment: omg, I've just spent 2h debuging and polishing my integration tests to pass list of IFormFile to the controller, it would work perfectly with a single IFormFile, but not with the list, the fact that the NAME parameter must MATCH the PARAMETER NAME is the key