# C#: Sending parameter with Content-Type Header in HTTP

Tags: c#, json, http-post, httpclient

I am trying to send the HTTP `post` request using `HTTP client`.while setting my  `Content-Type` header with `StringContent` method, I am getting the error:

> the format "application/json;ty=2 "is incorrect

My code is as follows:

```
string result2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
 var content = new StringContent(result2, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json; ty=2");
 var response = await client.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1:8080/~/in-cse/in-name", content);
                    var response_string = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

But in my HTTP Post format I have to include `ty=2` parameter along with `application/json`. I have tested this with `Postman`and it worked perfectly. How can I achieve the same thing here. I also even found you can add parameter to content type in the following format:
 `content := "Content-Type" ":" type "/" subtype *(";" parameter)` 
then why is it not working for me.
**EDIT:**even tried this:

```
 HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://127.0.0.1:8080/~/in-cse/in-name");
                    request.Content = new StringContent(result2, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json;ty=2");

                    client.SendAsync(request).ContinueWith(resposetask => { Console.WriteLine("response:{0}", resposetask.Result); });
```

same error i am getting

Comment: Can you please follow this link? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10679340/4222487

Comment: @FaizanRabbani i  have already referred to that link still it is not working.

Comment: Do you get same error?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani same error code mentioned in edits

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `TryAddWithoutValidation` in `DefaultRequestHeaders` in `HttpClient` like following:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json;ty=2");
```