# POST API with raw JSON using HttpClient in C#

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I cannot get the following POST request to work.  It returns with status message **400 (Bad Request)**, no matter what I try.

```
static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("<<REDACTED>>"); 
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

   // authorisation credentials go here, which work

  var model = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dialApi); //, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"); //.DeserializeObject<Hello>(result);
  var model1 = new StringContent(model, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
  var x = "{\"data\":{\"Dest\":\"<<REDACTED>>\"}}";

  //HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(path, model1);
  HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(path, new StringContent(x, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

The problem could be that the 'Content' -> 'Headers'  --> 'ContentType' is 'text/html' (it should be 'application/json', but I cannot seem to change this.  The default headers are already setup to 'application/json'

[image]

I should add that I have the API working in Postman, with the body sent as 'application/json' with the raw setting:

[image]

I wonder if anyone can help?

Update:

I have tried the alternative implementation given in the answer of the 'duplicate' question, which also does not work:

```
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, path);
        request.Content = new StringContent("{\"data\":{\"Dest\":\"<<>>redacted\"}}",
                                Encoding.UTF8,
                                "application/json");//CONTENT-TYPE header

        await client.SendAsync(request)
                  .ContinueWith(responseTask =>
                  {
                      Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", responseTask.Result);
                  });
```

With the following printed to the console:

[image]

Comment: Maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679214/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-header-for-an-httpclient-request

Comment: In your screenshot, are you checking the `Content` of the response? That could very well be text/html as it as the error message you got.

Comment: Use [HttpClient.PostAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpclient.postasync) instead of `PostAsJsonAsync`. Your payload is already a JSON string

Comment: @JLe - Yes it could be caused by the error response.

Comment: @Winthorpe use Fiddler or a similar debugging proxy to see what's actually being sent. `PostAsJsonAsync` is definitely not needed when you perform your own serialization. `client.PostAsync(model1)` is enough. BTW `Content-Type` is a content, not a request header. Using `DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
` results in a bad request

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I have tried 'HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(path, model1);' which also doesn't work.

Comment: I have a get request which works.  The problem is with the POST

Comment: Did you solve this? @Winthorpe i am having the same issue

Comment: @Decoder94 - I'm afraid I can recall what the solution was.  I haven't used the httpClient in .NET for a long time.

Comment: try this approach,It works private static async Task PostJsonContent(string uri, HttpClient httpClient)
{
    var postUser = new User { Name = "Steve Gordon" };

    var postRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri)
    {
        Content = JsonContent.Create(postUser)
    };

    var postResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(postRequest);

    postResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}