# Is it possible to set the Default Content-Type to "application/json;v=2.0"

Tags: c#, rest, http-headers, asp.net-web-api2

Is it possible to set the Default Content-Type to "application/json;v=2.0". I say default because I'm using a HttpClient class and I use the DefaultRequestHeaders to set my proxies to default values.

I followed this example to create my headers https://stackoverflow.com/a/10679340/196526 but I also use versioning and information about versioning is saved in ContenT-Type

```
public class BankAccountProxy
{
    public void SetToken()
    {
        Client = new HttpClient();
        Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiRoute"]);
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Token", ApiInformations.ApiToken);
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders
            .Accept
            .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue($"application/json;v=2.0"));
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<BankAccount>> Get()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.GetAsync($"/api/BankAccount/");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        IEnumerable<BankAccount> bankAccount;
        bankAccount = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<BankAccount>>();
        return bankAccount;
    }
}
```

When I run this code I get a

> Exception message: The format of value 'application/json;v=2.0' is
>   invalid.

Because of the v=2.0 that is probably not a valid MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.

What I want is to be sure I always send the version information in my Content-Type header value. How can I initialize it? How can I tell my code my default content type is not a quality header but a valid one.

For information here is my query perfectly working on Postman:

[image]

Comment: Can you try if this works , Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json;v=2.0");

Comment: I think it works but the one I need is "Content-Type" and when I add Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json;v=2.0"); line I get a 'Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.' exception.

Comment: The documentation about Versioning API is here https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/Versioning-by-Media-Type

I don't understand why sometime they use the Content-Type and sometime the Accept header parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Use this code:

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://contenttypev2.free.beeceptor.com") }; // interceptor
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Token", "SOME_TOKEN"); // simplified

                var response = await client.GetJson2Async("/api/BankAccount/");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // simplified
                Console.WriteLine(data);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    class Json2Content : StringContent
    {
        public Json2Content(string content) : this(content, Encoding.Default) { }

        public Json2Content(string content, Encoding encoding) : base(content, encoding)
        {
            this.Headers.Clear();
            this.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            this.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("v", "2.0"));
            if (!encoding.Equals(Encoding.Default)) this.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = encoding.HeaderName;
        }
    }

    static class Json2Extensions
    {
        public static Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetJson2Async(this HttpClient client, string requestUri, string content = "", Encoding encoding = default)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUri) { Content = new Json2Content(content, encoding ?? Encoding.Default) };
            return client.SendAsync(request);
        }
    }
```

And this is the result:

[image]

#### Explanation

As mentioned by [carlosfigueira](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10679340/2355482):

> The content type is a header of the content, not of the request

So setting the `Accept` header like you did here:

```cs
Client.DefaultRequestHeaders
  .Accept
  .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue($"application/json;v=2.0"));
```

will not help your objective.

To simplify use of JSON v2 content type, you can use the wrapper class above as well as the extension method provided.

#### Note

Are you sure you want to set the `Content-Type` header? It is very uncommon to have content in a GET request.
If you want to signal the server that you wish to ***receive*** JSON v2 response, you should do it in the `Accept` header. Even the [API versioning document](https://github.com/Microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/wiki/Versioning-by-Media-Type) you have referenced in the comments to the question shows that the version number could be set in the `Accept` header *or* the `Content-Type` header. When there is content you can still, probably, use the 'Accept' header to set the version and you can do that as a default like so:

```cs
var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://contenttypev2.free.beeceptor.com") }; // interceptor
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Token", "SOME_TOKEN"); // simplified
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
var json2MediaType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
json2MediaType.Parameters.Clear();
json2MediaType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("v", "2.0"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(json2MediaType);

var response = await client.GetAsync("/api/BankAccount/");
...
```

resulting with:

[image]

Comment: i did test it yea this is the answer.