# Flurl get request with "Content-Type" header?

Tags: c#, .net, flurl

The API I am tasked with consuming requests a "Content-Type" with value "application/json" along with method/verb "GET".  When I attempt using Flurl, I get response "ProtocolViolationException: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.".

Is there a way to do this?  I was also trying with HttpClient (see [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679214/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-header-for-an-httpclient-request)).  (btw.. using .NET Framework 4.5).

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Accept" header instead of "Content-Type" header?

Comment: Does the API require that you send a request _body_ on a GET request? That's unusual and not supported by HttpClient on full framework by default, but can be worked around. Can you post your code that makes the call?

Comment: I am going to take a look again.  What is happening is same code for net core doesnt succeed in net framework 45 proj.  The lib versions are different but I cant figure what specifically is causing the failure.  I think the content-type is a red herring..

Comment: @ToddMenier, you are right about this being unusual. I also have a similar case where API I am consuming enforcing Content-Type Header for a GET call.

I am using Flurl and notice that Content-Type is not being sent across to API end point when it is a GET call regardless I add it explicitly in request headers.

Is there a way to ensure Content-Type pass through Flurl for a GET request.

Appreciate your thoughts on it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason why in you've got this exception is that the `Content-Type` header is meant to be used for the `POST/PUT` request payloads.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type):

> The Content-Type entity header is used to indicate the media type of the resource.

`HTTP GET` method has no payload, and there is no sense to have `Content-Type` in the request.

In Furl, if you use `Content-Type: application/json` with `POST` or `PUT`, make sure to provide actual payload: `null` is not an option.