# c# - HttpClient error: System.Net.WebException: 'Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.' (api POST)

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin

I'm trying to POST form data to an ASP.NET Core API, the controller is set up this way:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<string> Post(
    [FromForm]string loginname, 
    [FromForm]string password)
{
    // do stuff

    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
}
```

and this is the HttpClient in the Xamarin.Forms app:

```
private async Task<LoginResponse> Login(string loginname, string password, string ip)
{

    string url = "http://192.168.1.27:5000/api/login";
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpContent formdata = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("loginname", loginname),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password)
        });

        HttpResponseMessage response;

        using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url) { Content = formdata })
            response = await httpClient.SendAsync(req);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponse>(response.ToString());
    }
}
```

I keep getting the following error after trying for so much time:

> HttpClient error: System.Net.WebException: 'Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.'

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I don't think you can pull two parameters from the body like that.  The model binding will try to bind to a single parameter unless it's from different sources like the URL, or headers.  Have you tried making a single class with login and password as properties then used that class as the parameter type?

Comment: That error message does not match the code in question. That usually is the result of a GET operation that tries to include a request message body which is not supported. Are you sure you rebuilt your code and that this Exception is being emitted on the code shown?

Comment: Does it help if you also set the request's content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Comment: @Igor it works fine with postman, only C# cannot get it.

also this is asp.net 2.2

Comment: @WiktorZychla how do I set that?

Comment: @YaRmgl: should I google that for you?

Comment: You did not answer my question. Make sure your code is rebuilt before you run it (do not accidentally run an older version due to a compile error). Also make sure the exception is being thrown by the code in question and not something that might be taking place before hand. I say this because the exception message does not match the code shown.

Comment: @YaRmgl: [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679214/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-header-for-an-httpclient-request), hope that helps.

Comment: httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")); does not work, @Igor I will do a try/catch to see the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I am really blind, I was calling a deprecated GET from another route on the OnClick, although @WiktorZychla pointed out that I needed to set the content type to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`