# Call WebApi Endpoint Passing in Object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, restsharp

I have the following endpoint

```
[HttpPost]
[DisableRequestSizeLimit]
[RequestFormLimits(KeyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue)]
public IActionResult PostData([FromForm]Data data)
```

The Data class looks like this

```
public class Data
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}
```

I am calling this endpoint in this way

```
var url = ...;

var client = new HttpClient();
var data = new
{
    a = "Foo",
    b = "Bar"
};
var result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, data);
```

But the data parameter in the PostData method always is null.  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: That's not an `out` parameter so what does `comes back` mean? `result` won't be null either, it will always contain the response

Comment: `FromForm`? but posting as JSON. Not form was went

Comment: `FromForm` that - forms don't use JSON - JSON was invented at least a decade later. Use a [FormUrlEncodedContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.formurlencodedcontent?view=netcore-3.0) instace with `PostAsync`. All it needs as input is anything that implements `IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>>` like a  `Dictionary<string,string>`

Comment: On the other hand, if that `PostData` method isn't used with forms, you could just remove `[FromForm]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your content type is `application/json` use `[FromBody]` instead of `[FromForm]`.

Comment: Now the PostData method does not fire at all.

Comment: Have you changed the ContentType to application/json?

Comment: You may also want to remove the RequestFormLimits attribute from the method as well.

Comment: Ok will do but I put that there because I will be passing quite large data.

Comment: Do I set the content type on the DefaultRequestHeaders?

Comment: @SachinKainth `PostAsJsonAsync` already sets the content type as `application/json`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679214/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-header-for-an-httpclient-request