# Getting 404 response from Web API on POST action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

A console application is making a call to an Web API but getting 404 response.

The `responseBytes` array in client below, when converted to string using `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes, 0, responseBytes.Length);` returns following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Not Found</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Not Found</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

**Client call**

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(action);//action=http://<my-app>/headcount/comparison/zip
    _logger.InfoFormat("downloading files from {0}", action);
    var response = await client.PostAsync(action, new StringContent(jsonInString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
    responseBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
}
```

**Controller/action:**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class HeadcountController : ControllerBase
{

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("comparison/zip")]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    public IActionResult GetReports(ReportRequest request)
    {
        //action details...never reached
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the value of action?

Comment: @ZoiloReyes the value of action is http://<my-app>/headcount/comparison/zip

Comment: You are showing us all the server stuff -- what are you doing in your client?

Comment: @Hogan no. from what i understand `[controller]` is a special keyword not a literal. please see this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#binding-source-parameter-inference

Comment: Not sure if I remember correctly but aren't these routes case sensitive and so `[controller]` should be replaced with "Headcount" (note the upper case "H")... ?

Comment: Perhaps the ReportRequest expected to be from route while you sending in body?

Comment: It`s not a bad idea to test the Api with Postman before to be sure about the first part.

Comment: Nothing seems to be wrong, do GET responses give you the expected result?

Comment: @ZoiloReyes yes. GET is working fine.

Comment: Then the json string format could be related. Can you show the string you are sending? or at least something similar.

Comment: @NullReference added Startup.cs

Comment: Comment out https redirection or call https://<my-app>/headcount/comparison/zip if you have a SSL certificate

Comment: @ZoiloReyes added watch to jsonString in Visual Studio debugger and it formats correctly using JSON Visualizer.

Comment: @ZoiloReyes commented out https redirection. no luck. im going to change `ReportRequest` to use only string properties to rule out json issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the `client` content type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

```
    client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Comment: `HttpClient` does not have `Headers` property. And doing `DefaultRequestHeaders.Add` causes runtime exception https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Hmm. I've more experience with the back end side. We had to set the content type for our front end to get our back end to accept POSTs. Are you able to try with any other libraries?

Comment: Maybe you will find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679214/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-header-for-an-httpclient-request

Comment: My development machine's hosts file was pointing to production API which did not have the controller/action I was calling. Sigghh....