# .Net Core 3.1 HttpClient Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation Not Working

Tags: c#

I am probably missing something really simple but I just cannot find it.

An API I am working with demands the inclusion of a Content-Type header even with GETs.

I am struggling to add the header to my request.

Here is the code that builds the httpclient:

```
public static async Task<HttpClient> Authenticate(string baseUrl, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

        string toBeHashed = $"client_id={clientId}&client_secret={clientSecret}";
        string hashed = sha256_hash(toBeHashed);

        AuthRequest request = new AuthRequest
        {
            client_id = clientId,
            hash = hashed
        };

        StringContentWithoutCharset body = new StringContentWithoutCharset(JsonSerializer.Serialize(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync($"{baseUrl}authenticate", body);

        AuthResponse result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<AuthResponse>(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());

        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.data.token);
        

        return httpClient;
    }
```

And here is 2 different attempts at making a GET call.

When I look in Fiddler the Content-Type is missing from the headers:

```
public class Functions
{
    private HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly string _baseUrl;

    public Functions(string baseUrl, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        _httpClient = Helpers.Authenticate(baseUrl, clientId, clientSecret).Result;
        _baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }

    public async Task ProductList()
    {
        // this doesn't work
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"{_baseUrl}products");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response1 = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        ProductList result1 = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<ProductList>(await response1.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());

        // nor does this
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{_baseUrl}products");
        ProductList result2 = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<ProductList>(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the header already has `Content-Type` entry. Also, you can check the return of `TryAddWithoutValidation`

Comment: @Vernou the result of TryAddWithoutValidation is false and there is no Content-Type Entry in Fiddler... although it was when i first called for the API token. Could that affect it?

Comment: Content-Type is to specify the content's type of the request, but GET request don't have a content. I miss something in your question?

Comment: I completely agree! But, this API responds with a 400 Bad Request when it's not present even on a GET. When i add the content-type manually in Fiddler i get a result for the products. Their API shouldn't demand this content-type on a GET but it does :(

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679214/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-header-for-an-httpclient-request

Comment: Hacky, but works: just add this line: `request.Content = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");` This should add the header. ~~Alternatively, if you don't want to specify the encoding, then add an empty `StringContent`, then `request.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/json");`~~ (edit: the last one doesn't work properly)

Comment: @Riwen that worked!! I love you!

Comment: Haha, you're welcome man.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reposting my comment as an answer, so that it's helpful for everyone facing the same.

You can't use `Content-Type` as request header as godot pointed out, because it's not really that, as far as .NET is concerned. However, it is also a "content header" (which *is* a request header, technically speaking). Content headers are perfectly valid for `POST` and `PUT` requests. Therefore, as a hacky solution (`GET` requests are not supposed to have content), you can add this line:

`request.Content = new StringContent("", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");`

This adds an empty `StringRequest`, and as the third argument, you can actually specify the `Content-Type`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using response header as a request header.

[TryWithoutValidation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpheaders.tryaddwithoutvalidation?view=netcore-3.1) method returns `false` in your example because you are using response header as a request header. If you try to use `Add` method instead of `TryWithoutValidation` you see actual reason of error.

```
request.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/json");
```

and you receive:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
> occurred in System.Net.Http.dll: 'Misused header name. Make sure
> request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers
> with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent
> objects.'

So use **Accept** header instead of **Content-type**

```
request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "application/json");
```

Comment: My request already contains "Accept: application/json". As explained in my question the API I am working with is incorrectly demanding that the "Content-Type" header is present even for GETs

Comment: so you can't have "Content-Type" header in your request, because it is a response header

Comment: @godot yes, your explanation is correct, but OPs API is not. Thats why OP asked how to   add a header to a GET request.