# Convert RestShapr RestRequest to native HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient, restsharp

I have this REST request; I'm trying to convert it to `HttpClient`. I don't want to use `RestSharp` in my application.

I'm not sure how to send over an empty body in the request: I keep getting "bad request" when I send a response.

Basically, I call a `post` method to log in a user below. It works in RestSharp, but the request needs an empty body to be successful.

```cs
var client = new RestClient(Token.Location + "/users/api/login");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", Token.Value);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddJsonBody(JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { }));
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

I'm trying to convert this piece of code to use `HttpClient` in .net core 3.1.

Here is what I have tried:

```cs
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", Token.Value);


var stringContent = new StringContent(string.Empty);
var res = await client.PostAsync(Token.Location + "/users/api/login", stringContent);

var data = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I've also tried

```cs
...
var content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { }), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var res = await client.PostAsync(Token.Location + "/users/api/login", content);
...
var res = await client.PostAsync(Token.Location + "/users/api/login", null);
...
var res = await client.PostAsync(Token.Location + "/users/api/login", "Empty string");
```

I keep getting "bad request" because I'm not sending over an empty body.
I've tried in postman and it works with an empty raw body of `{}`. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10679340/6789816) answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you want to do is make sure you are using a [shared HttpClient](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/). If you are in ASP.NET Core, use `IHttpClientFactory`. You can [learn why here](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclient-connection-pooling-in-dotnet-core).

Since you are going to share your `HttpClient`, it's good to *not* use `DefaultReqestHeaders` as it will affect all requests, and the header dictionary isn't thread-safe. So if one thread is modifying the collection at the same time another one is, you will crash.

That's not saying that you should *never* use `DefaultRequestHeaders`. They are handy if you don't want to set the same header over and over. You set the value once and all requests share that value.

With that in mind, it is always good to use `SendAsync`. This method takes a `HttpRequestMessasage` which allows you to isolate the headers to that one request.

A typical usage scenario is:

```
using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
    new Uri("https://www.example.com")))
{
    req.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("token");
    using (var resp = await _client.SendAsync(req))
    {
        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var data = resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

This will send a GET request to `https://www.example.com` with an `Authorization` header with the value `token`.

The `HttpRequestMessage` has its own set of headers which is used in conjunction with the `DefaultRequestHeaders`.

The next thing to consider, and this is out of the scope of your question, but it's worth bringing up: Try to use `UriBuilder` when creating your URLs with pieces.

For example:

```
var uri = new UriBuilder(Token.Location) { Path = "/users/api/login" }.Uri;
```

Now you don't have to worry if `Token.Location` ends with `/` or not. The framework will make sure it's well-formed.

As far as posting an object as JSON, here is an example using `Newtonsoft.Json` package:

```
using (var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,
    new Uri("https://www.example.com")))
{
    req.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("token");
    req.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    req.Content = new StringContent(
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(theObjectToSend),
        Encoding.UTF8,
        "application/json");

    using (var resp = await _client.SendAsync(req))
    {
        resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(
            await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
}
```

This will serialize and apply the appropriate headers to your request. It will then read the request back and deserialize it to `object`. You'd want to replace `object` with a model you create so it's easy to read.

I know this answer is overblown for what you are asking, but I like to give some tips when people first start out with `HttpClient`, because there are a few "gotcha's" that get missed.

So, for your answer, take the code above and replace `theObjectToSend` with `new {}` and see what happens.

If it still isn't working, using something like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to debug your HTTP calls to see what you are missing.

Comment: Excelent! Thanks for the answer and the tips!

Comment: @Train -- did changing things around make it work? If not, I'd be more than happy to help you troubleshoot. It's hard to fix your issue since I can't hit your endpoints myself.