# Spotify API - get request C#

Tags: c#, .net, spotify

I am trying to get saved tracks from Spotify, what am I doing wrong?

```
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {              
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage resp = await client.GetAsync("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks");

            string responseBody = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
        }
```

This is a request sample from the [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/operations/get-users-saved-tracks):

> curl --request GET 
> --url https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks 
> --header 'Authorization: ' 
> --header 'Content-Type: application/json'

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong?  In what way does this fail?

Comment: Hello, David! The mistake is: "Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects."

Comment: Might be a dupe of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679214/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-header-for-an-httpclient-request)

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like the `Content-Type` header?  After all, a GET request doesn't *have* "content".  Try without that header, or with sending an `Accepts` header of `application/json`.  It's possible this was an oversight in the API docs, or some nebulous interpretation of standards between the vendors.

Comment: Yea I'd probably just remove `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");` - I don't think it actually does anything since you're not POST'ing content.

Comment: Tried without content type - returns this array: "
  "error" : {
    "status" : 403,
    "message" : "Insufficient client scope"
  }
}".

Comment: I think that's a new problem.  Seems like maybe the OAuth token is bad?

Comment: Same error with Accepts :(

Comment: Checked token again.

Comment: I'm not an OAuth expert, but I think sometimes when you request a token you have to request certain scopes..  I think you're doing something wrong when you get your token, but we can't see that part of the code..