# Content-Type returned by HEAD request sent using C# HttpClient is incorrect; however, Postman returns the correct Content-Type

Tags: c#, .net, rest, http, .net-core

I must get the Content-Type of an [URL](https://lookaside.fbsbx.com/ig_messaging_cdn/?asset_id=17946283682039557&signature=Abwa1_6ve4FhYpDme2-z-DOIVdPVItzsSQcm9KuXimflvarObfnbUX1RasAx9twIVf7rkp2PzavIuUUyzQ2ljjQOhtvM4aEJ3Sfu9KKItK_7gVPGMtX__9Wri8ylmFcpjuz91BFNlbfmr_82_uNb8LWRbRcfKaD1oRys6z-lVzHXYlnn1sl1yEXNs-0R2T7z3VT21u1TnQrzHObDociBeDtkRv2ge5ZG) using .NET.

However, it's returning `text/html` for this URL, while Postman returns the correct Content-Type `video/mp4`. For several others file URLs, .NET returns the correct Content-Type, but not for this.

My code:

```
string uriString = "INSERT_URL_HERE";
HttpClient httpClient = new();
try
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = new(HttpMethod.Head, uriString);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    string contentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("\nThe Content-Type of the resource is: {0}\n", contentType);
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nException caught!");
    Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}\n", exception.Message);
}
```

Postman response:

[image: Postman response]

Comment: Possibly the site you're using expects a `User-Agent` header, which .NET doesn't send by default. If not: is it only head requests that do this, or get requests too?

Comment: Perhaps [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679214/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-header-for-an-httpclient-request?rq=1#comment41931086_10679340) is what you're hitting?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar, I set the user-agent and it worked. Wonderful! Can you answer the thread with your solution? Because that way I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Relevant https://towardsdatascience.com/the-user-agent-that-crazy-string-underpinning-a-bunch-of-analytics-86507ef632f0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `User-Agent` header was not being sent, as @DiplomacyNotWar stated. After setting the `User-Agent` header value it worked!

PS: I used the same `User-Agent` of Google Chrome.

```
string browserUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";
request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", browserUserAgent);
```