# How to set "custom" Content-Type of an HttpClient request in DOT NET CORE?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, httpclient, content-type

I'm trying to set Content-Type as **"application/x.example.hr.employee.email+json;version=1"** of an HttpClient request as required by the API I am calling. The API is of type **GET** and accepts a **JSON body** (containing list of emails).

I'm successfully able to set **Accept** header to **"application/x.example.hr.employee+json;version=1"**. In this case, both - Accept and Content-Type need to be set as mentioned, otherwise API throws a error of 400 (Bad request). I tried [How do you set the Content-Type header for an HttpClient request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679214/how-do-you-set-the-content-type-header-for-an-httpclient-request) and several other options but getting run time error when I try to set Content-Type other than **"application/json"**.

This type needs to be applied on the request content but not in the header Content-Type. Below is one of the code snippet I tried:

```
_httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://example.com/");
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.Accept, "application/x.example.hr.employee+json;version=1");
//_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Type", "application/x.example.hr.employee.email+json;version=1"); // Throws exception

List<string> strEmail = new List<string>
{
     employeeEmail
};
var jsonEmail = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strEmail);

var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    RequestUri = new Uri("http://example.com/employees"),
    Content = new StringContent(jsonEmail, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x.example.hr.employee.email+json;version=1")
};

//var response = _httpClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);

await _httpClient.SendAsync(request)
    .ContinueWith(responseTask =>
    {
        var response = responseTask;
    });
```

Comment: What runtime error are you getting?

Comment: @ckuri The format of value 'application/x.example.hr.employee.email+json;version=1' is invalid.

Comment: I believe the problem is not the header, but the `new StringContent` part. The `StringContent` has another constructor that only takes in the `content` and the `encoding`. Can you remove the third parameter from the `StringContent` constructor call and see how that goes?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Tried as you suggested, getting **Bad Request** response from API. Inspected the request body, when I took off the third param from `StringContent`, it set `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`.

Comment: Remove the version from the media type then, that's what throws it off and it says it's not valid. Use only `application/x.example.hr.employee.email+json` when you build the `StringContent`

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Still getting bad request response from API :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a reason that don't fully understand, the `"application/x.example.hr.employee.email+json;version=1"` media type is not correctly parsed whenever you build a `StringContent` (or actually a `MediaTypeHeaderValue`).

I did find a workaround for this:

```cs
List<string> strEmail = new List<string> {
    employeeEmail
};
var jsonEmail = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(strEmail);
var content = new StringContent(jsonEmail, Encoding.UTF8);
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x.example.hr.employee.email+json");
content.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("version", "1"));

var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    RequestUri = new Uri("http://example.com/employees"),
    Content = content
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It's odd that the `MediaTypeHeaderValue` constructor (which is what `StringContent` calls) doesn't accept "application/x.example.hr.employee.email+json; version=1".

However, `MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse` does.

```
var contentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x.example.hr.employee.email+json; version=1");
var content = new StringContent(jsonEmail, Encoding.UTF8, contentType);
```

If you're stuck on .NET 6 and below:

```
var content = new StringContent(jsonEmail, Encoding.UTF8);
content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x.example.hr.employee.email+json; version=1");
```

See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/20272) for a discussion.

Comment: Nice find. It might be a bug.

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu Yeah, I found a github issue (see the edit) which suggests that the current behaviour is out of spec.

Comment: Wow. So old... I am surprised this was not addressed by now. Anyways, I am glad there are workarounds for it.

Comment: `MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse` returns `MediaTypeHeaderValue` type, whereas `StringContent` constructor is expectiong string as it's 3rd parameter. Am I missing something here? @canton7

Comment: @Kibria You're missing [the overload which takes a `MediaTypeHeaderValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-net-http-stringcontent-ctor(system-string-system-text-encoding-system-net-http-headers-mediatypeheadervalue))

Comment: @canton7 It seems `mediaType` as `MediaTypeHeaderValue` is introduced in .NET 7. I'm using .NET 5, which is capable of expecting `mediaType` as `string`.

Comment: @Kibria In that case you can take part of the approach taken by OctavianMărculescu, see the edit

Comment: @canton7 yes that approach resolved the issue, and it works fine. Thanks for the help :)