# Set Content-Type header in C# .NET Framework in GET request

Tags: c#, .net, webapi

I need to call an external API to get information. The method is GET, but there is a check on their side to send a valid Content-Type media header to work (in this case, application/json).

I know that in GET request there is no need to send Content-Type because most of the times (or should be) you do not pass body data. This is the case in this method because you do not need to pass body data. However, i need to set `Content-Type: application/json` so the method can return a valid response, because is an external API and they can not change it.

How can I set this header in a GET request? I tried a lot of things but with no success. I am using `HttpClient`, but other options could be valid.

Comment: @bryanbcook your first link is using POST method. I tried before using GET, but it does not work. I need to set in a GET request

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16959464/74261 is the answer.

Comment: @nothrow the same as i answered before. It only works with POST method, but not using GET. (exception: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type)

Answer (score 1):

For .NET Core:

You can assign empty content and set the headers on that:

```
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://google.com");
    request.Content = new ByteArrayContent(Array.Empty<byte>());
    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
    await client.SendAsync(request);
```

For .NET Framework, see the comments

Comment: To note, you can also set up a named http client as a service and set your headers automatically so you don;t have to type it over and over.

Comment: @JeffB does that work for content headers though? I assume you would get a similar error that Content-Type is not a request header...

Comment: It should, headers are agnostic to the content of the request at creation time. It could complain because you are trying to add a header that is technically not needed for a GET request...

Comment: @JineappleAra not working. I get this exception: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I assumed .NET Core but I see now you wrote .NET Framework. Try this answer in that case? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41231353/21398414

Comment: @JineappleAra Yes, not the same approach but similar. I tried a thing an it worked. This is what i did and it worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/77497062/15277024. Thanks for your answer!