# jQuery Ajax GET and contentType?

Tags: jquery

Regarding : (jQuery ajax method) :

Does  `contentType`  property is counted when the request itself is a  `GET` request ?
(example)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/webservices/xxx.asmx/yyy",
    data: JSON.stringify({ Markers: markers }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",.......

});
```

p.s.

*contentType is the form of data which i send to the server

dataType is the form of data which i EXPECT to get from server.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need a content type for http get requests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661596/do-i-need-a-content-type-for-http-get-requests)

Comment: @adeneo perfectly duplicate.  thanks. didnt see that.( however i will vote to delete)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt), it's not forbidden to use the request body in GET requests.
However, I'd like to know of an client implementation which does send data in the body and an server implementation which parses data in the body of GET requests.

So basically, no, the `Content-Type` header is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Get requests should not have content-type because they do not have request body.
So I would say no, it's not needed.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum they have an empty body IMHO

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum did i say its forbidden or impossible ? I jsut said that the body is empty. you can create a fiddler request with get and full body content and it still gonna work.