# Ajax GET with content type set to json. Is this valid?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have seen that it's possible to set the content type of a Ajax POST request to json. From what I understand this means that the data send (which you should stringify first) will be sent as json in the body of he request.

Is it therefore a mistake to set the content type to json when doing an Ajax GET request? Can you send json as part of the url query string?

Much thanks

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17725110/jquery-ajax-get-and-contenttype). When you're requesting something via GET, the body is empty, and the content type refers to the data type of the body.

Comment: You can still send data to a GET request using for example `data: { id: someValue }`. There is no need to stringify it, but if you do (using `data: JSON.stringify({ id: someValue })`) then you do need to set the `contentType` to 'json'

Comment: @StephenMuecke you comment about setting the content type to json seems to contract David's comment.

Comment: No it doesn't. I'm saying if you do send data using the `data:` option and you stringify it, then you can set the `contentType` option. But your claim that _you should stringify first_ is wrong - you do not need to stringify it.

Comment: With a POST can I ask what is the purpose of setting the content type to json (e.g. contentType: "application/json") and not using the stringify? How will the data be transmitted? What is the advantage of using JSON.stringify?