# Effect to show information retrieved on innerHTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an `ajax call()` to load some specific information about a product:

```
function fnShowDetProd(code, size) {    
    mod.open("GET", "control/_showdetailproduct.asp?cod="+code+"&size="+size, true);    
    mod.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");    
    mod.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (mod.readyState == 4) {          
            document.getElementById("showDetails").innerHTML = mod.responseText;            
        }
    };
    mod.send(null)  
}
```

I call this function in my row `onClick` event:

```
 fnMostDetProd(selectedRow[0], selectedRow[1]);
```

Where selectedRow[0] and [1] are parameters of the clicked line.

I'm wondering if it's that possible to add a `jQuery` effect like `fadeIn()` to show the information retrieved on `showDetails` element.

Using `jQuery 1.8.3` and `jQuery ui 1.10.1`.

Comment: Why do you set the `Content-Type` Request header of a GET call?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Have you tried it? Just right after setting the innerHTML… Btw, you should use jQuery if it's available

Comment: Because of charset problems with database

Comment: [Impossible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5661596/1048572). Maybe you need a response header (set on the server side)?

Comment: @Bergi. I don't know exactly why, but if I cut it off the content loaded shows weird chars.

Comment: Maybe your server is configured weirdly to reflect the request header in the response or to use it for some internal setup. Still, that's not how it *should* work.

Comment: Could be that. Also, this piece of code is for beta tests only. I may have to collect some garbage on my code later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
function fnShowDetProd(code, size) {    
    mod.open("GET", "control/_showdetailproduct.asp?cod="+code+"&size="+size, true);    
    mod.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");    
    mod.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (mod.readyState == 4) {          
        $("#showDetails").hide();
        $("#showDetails").html(mod.responseText);
        $("#showDetails").fadeIn();
    }
};
mod.send(null)
}
```

Comment: I don't know why, but seems jQuery doesn't work inside this ajax function. I've tried almost everything to make it work, without success. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I found out what was wrong and your answer worked fine. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: **http://jsfiddle.net/X5jUC/**

Make your div hidden...

```
<div id="showDetails" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Then all you have to do is this...

```
$("#showDetails").html('replace this with your mod.responseText').fadeIn( 3000, function() {
    // Animation complete
});
```

3000 means it takes 3 seconds to fade in, nice and slow.  Increase it or decrease it to your liking.

Comment: Sure it does. This is basic jQuery, the fiddle show it works. We can figure it out. Show me your `div` code.