# Requestmapping not working when there is headers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In My controller i have a method below which is working well

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchresults",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public SearchResponse searchResults(
@PathVariable("domain") String domain,
@RequestParam(value="rowCount" , defaultValue="0",  required=false) Integer rowCount,
HttpServletRequest req){}
```

but the same thing is not working when adding headers,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchresults", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public SearchResponse searchResults(
@PathVariable("domain") String domain,
@RequestParam(value="rowCount" , defaultValue="0",  required=false) Integer rowCount,
HttpServletRequest req){}
```

Exception :
Representation: null org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.NoSuchRequestHandlingMethodException: No matching handler method found for servle
t request: path '/search/searchresults.json', method 'GET',

I tried as follows,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchresults", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers = {"content-type=application/json,charset=UTF-8"})
```

but it throws,
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "charset=UTF-8" does not contain '/'

How to resolve it

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add the headers names :|

`application/json` is the **Content-Type**, while `UTF-8` is the **Charset**.

Take a look at the [complete list of HTTP headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

The correct mapping will then be :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchresults", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                       headers = {"content-type=application/json,charset=UTF-8"})
```

That said, it's worth knowing that the ContentType [should be specified only for POST and PUT requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16693884/1654265).

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the header name also, which is `content-type`. Change this:

```
headers ="application/json;charset=UTF-8"
```

to

```
headers = {"content-type=application/json,charset=UTF-8"}
```

Comment: I tried headers = {"content-type=application/json,charset=UTF-8"} but it throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: "charset=UTF-8" does not contain '/'

Answer (score 0):

Change `headers` to `produces`

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchresults", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public SearchResponse searchResults(
@PathVariable("domain") String domain,
@RequestParam(value="rowCount" , defaultValue="0",  required=false) Integer rowCount,
HttpServletRequest req){}
```

Ideally you should use `@RestController` if you are using Spring 4

Answer (score 0):

Use ; instead of ,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/searchresults", method = RequestMethod.GET,headers = {"content-type=application/json;charset=UTF-8"})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for those who use WebLogic, while maybe other app servers an do the similar, here is what worked for me in **weblogic.xml**

```
<wls:charset-params>
        <wls:input-charset>
              <wls:resource-path>/restful</wls:resource-path>
              <wls:java-charset-name>UTF-8</wls:java-charset-name>
        </wls:input-charset>
</wls:charset-params>
```

My Request Mapping annotation looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/echo", produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8", headers = "Accept=*/*")
```

adding

```
headers = {"content-type=application/json,charset=UTF-8"}
```

didn't help and I am puzzled why, but I got away somehow. HTH

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful (being stuck with Spring 3.0.x):

```
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> getResponse() {
  String body = ...
  MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
  headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
  return new ResponseEntity<String>(body, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```