# ContentType is null when making Get requests using ServiceStack JsonServiceClient

Tags: servicestack

In my integration tests, ContentType is null when I make Get requests using ServiceStack's JsonServiceClient.  However all the Post requests have a ContentType.  Is it excluded on purpose? ie. [Do I need a content type for http get requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661596/do-i-need-a-content-type-for-http-get-requests)

Is there a way I can set the ContentType using this client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `Content-Type` for **GET** Requests since it doesn't have a Request body.

The `Content-Type` on the Request Header specifies what format the Request Body is in, likewise when on the Response Body specifies what format the Response Body is in.

You may instead be after the `Accept` HTTP Request Header which tells the server the preferred Content Types it would like the Response in.