# Browser encoding HTTP requests

Tags: http, browser

What encoding does browser use when sending HTTP requests?

I mean when browser sends the very first request how can it be sure that the encoding it uses will be understood by the server?

Example:

```
GET /hello.htm HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE5.01; Windows NT)
Host: www.tutorialspoint.com
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Comment: what *exactly* do you mean by "encoding" in this context?

Comment: @JulianReschke I mean when sending the HTTP request it must be encoded somehow e.g UTF-8, UTF-16. How does it know encoding can the server decode?

Comment: So you're talking about the URI?

Comment: @JulianReschke No, I am talking about the HTTP request itself.

Comment: URI, header fields, or payload?

Answer (score 1):

A browser can tell the server explicitly which encoding is used thanks to `Content-type` header. `Content-type` might contains `charset`, but it's possible to infer the encoding by type. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9254967/3866610), `application/json`:

> Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 designates the content
>   to be in JSON format, encoded in the UTF-8 character encoding.
>   Designating the encoding is somewhat redundant for JSON, since the
>   default (only?) encoding for JSON is UTF-8. So in this case the
>   receiving server apparently is happy knowing that it's dealing with
>   JSON and assumes that the encoding is UTF-8 by default, that's why it
>   works with or without the header.

What about the situation that `Content-type` is [not defined in request](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16693884/3866610)?

> A sender that generates a message containing a payload body SHOULD
>   generate a Content-Type header field in that message unless the
>   intended media type of the enclosed representation is unknown to the
>   sender. If a Content-Type header field is not present, the recipient
>   MAY either assume a media type of "application/octet-stream"
>   ([RFC2046], Section 4.5.1) or examine the data to determine its type.