# Axios .get request weird behaviour

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I have the following get request:

```
return axios
    .get<ArticlesResponse>(SUGGESTED_ARTICLES, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then(onRequestSuccess)
    .catch(onRequestError);
```

It returns me an object with the data I need, however, the data field inside the object is a string instead of an actual object. Anyone has any ideea about why? I looked it up and saw that adding that header above will fix the issue but it doesn't. Thanks in advance!

My onRequestSucces is:

```
export function onRequestSuccess<T = any>(response: AxiosResponse<T>) {
  console.log('Request Successful!', response);

  return response.data;
}
```

`JSON.Parse()` also won't fix it.

Comment: Are you able to show a snippet of the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be due to the API returning a response that contains **invalid JSON** data, now JSON.parse would throw an error, but Axios manages the exception by setting the invalid JSON as string in the data property. Try using the Fetch API.

Comment: Actually, this is what it was about. Just found it right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a GET request (doesn't have a body) the 'Content-Type' is not being useful. This header is used to tell the server which type of content you're sending, but you're sending none. You should use it only on POST/PUT requests.

[See this question for more details on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661596/do-i-need-a-content-type-header-for-http-get-requests).

In order for your request to be read as JSON you have to set the header in the **server**. This will tell the browser you're **receiving** a JSON, which will then be parsed automatically by axios.