# WSO2 EI 6.6 Content-Type is null for GET requests

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm having an API endpoint defined in WSO2 EI Integration studio. When I send this endpoint a `GET` request, the `$axis2:ContentType` header of the request is getting null as soon as it comes inside the EI (Beginning of inSequence) . Is there a way to preserve this header and send it out of the EI. Any idea how to do this ?

NOTE: This is not happening for `POST` requests.

API endpoint

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/eirouter_test" name="eirouter_test" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST GET">
        <inSequence>
            <log level="custom">
                <property expression="$axis2:ContentType" name="original-content-type" />
            </log>
            
            <respond description="Send result to the client"/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence />
        <faultSequence />
    </resource>
</api>
```

Request CURL

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8290/eirouter_test/eb805bbe-6c3e-414d-a380-857b6f89607c' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

EI Logs

```
[2021-06-01 10:54:41,457]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:eirouter_test} original-content-type = null
```

Answer (score 0):

In short answer, the `Content-Type` HTTP header should be set only for `PUT` and `POST` requests. There was very similar question: [Do I need a content-type header for HTTP GET requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661596/do-i-need-a-content-type-header-for-http-get-requests)
 with very good explanations.

So that is not WSO2 problem, but that is how works HTTP with `Content-Type` header.